# How can I prevent a bootstrap 4 column from shrinking on shorter text?

Tags: razor, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a razor page with a three column grid such that:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
{
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 align-self-center order-first">Question Text</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-4 align-self-center">Fixed Width Table</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 align-self-center order-last">Other Text</div>
</div>
}
```

The text in the first column is long enough to stretch over 2 lines in the lg screen size, and everything is fine and lined up.  But on some questions the text is short and the first column shrinks, throwing alignment out of whack.

How can i fix this?

Attached a screenshot (this is in Arabic, one of the languages the page handles, which evidently is more compact than English...).

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot because I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: @Hossam - attached!

Comment: I still can't reproduce the issue using the structure you sent above, you need to create a Plnkr test code and attach the url here. But it looks like you have a styling that overrides bootstrap's default styling in this part.

Did you set the `dir="rtl"` in the body tag, right?

Comment: correct about the rtl

Comment: If it is not important that columns line up, use `col` for the one you want to take all the available width and `col-auto` for the rest.

Comment: but my problem is that I want the columns to line up as i mentioned in the OP @mahan

Comment: Hard to answer since you have not included your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problems I had were solved with two measures which I will record here for the benefit of anyone with similar 'strange' issues with bootstrap 4 columns.

a) DO NOT set margins left or right on divs that are rows or columns.
b) Use .w-100 on rows that have columns with variable length content in them.